# Is screen capturing/recording in NativeClient possible?

Tags: google-chrome-app, screen-capture, google-nativeclient

I am looking into creating a screen sharing application and would like to leverage native client to do so, but is that possible.

I know that chrome has the desktop sharing api, but this does not work for full screen applications such as video games so that is not an option.

So is it feasible for me to leverage native client for screen capturing/recording/sharing.

Comment: You'll probably have to use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) instead.

Comment: what was the final result, I am trying to achieve the same thing, but I can not find resources